# Convergence/Divergence in Probability for a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $\psi_n:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the random variable

$$
\psi_n(x)=\sum_{l=0}^{2^k}(-1)^l\mathbb{I}_{\left[\frac{l}{2^k},\frac{l+1}{2^k}\right)}(x)\text{ where k is such that }2^k\le n<2^{k+1},
$$

on the probability space $([0,1),\mathcal{B},m)$.

**Does $\psi_n$ converge in probability to any random variable?**

So far I have that $\psi_n\in\{-1,+1\}$ and

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left[\psi_n=1\right]&=\sum_{l\text{ even number}}^{2^k}m\left(\left[\frac{l}{2^k},\frac{l+1}{2^k}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2},\\
\mathbb{P}\left[\psi_n=-1\right]&=\sum_{l\text{ odd number}}^{2^k-1}m\left(\left[\frac{l}{2^k},\frac{l+1}{2^k}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

But I am not sure of how to proceed from here on.

Comment: How to proceed?  Write the definition of convergence in probability.

Comment: Remember that a sequence which converges in probability has a subsequence which converges almost surely

Comment: I want to know exactly how to prove/disprove convergence in probability for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\psi_n\stackrel{m}{\to} \psi$ for some $\psi$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$
$$m(|\psi_{2^n}-\psi_{2^{n+1}}|>\varepsilon)\leq m(|\psi_{2^n}-\psi|>\varepsilon/2)+m(|\psi_{2^{n+1}}-\psi|>\varepsilon/2)\to 0$$
However for $0<\varepsilon <2$ we have $m(|\psi_{2^n}-\psi_{2^{n+1}}|>\varepsilon)=1/2$, a contradiction.